# How to grant access to user for Aurora on Cloud Foundry?

Tags: mysql, cloud-foundry, amazon-aurora

My company uses Aurora database on Cloudfoundry. I have an application running which is bound to a Aurora database service. After clicking through Application -> Variables in Stratos UI I can see environment variables for the Aurora database such as hostname, username, password, database, etc.

How I want to connect to the database - either from Ubuntu mysql terminal tool as

```
mysql -u user1 -p -h abcdef.rds.amazonaws.com -P 1234 -D mydb123
```

or from Python as

```
import pymysql.cursors
connection = pymysql.connect(host='abcdef.rds.amazonaws.com', user='user1', 
    password='***', db='mydb123',cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
```

For both calls I do get a response as follows:

```
pymysql.err.OperationalError: (1045, "Access denied for user 'user1 '@'1.2.3.4' (using password: YES)")
```

How do I grant my user `user1` access rights? I cannot find anything inside the Stratos UI.

I have created the Aurora db service myself.

Comment: I don't know about Aurora, but for MySQL a user is both the username & a hostname, where the hostname restricts the IP/host from which that user can access the DB. For example, `root@localhost` would only allow the root user to connect if they're doing so from the local machine. The error is saying `user1@1.2.3.4` is denied. It's possible `user1` and `password` are correct, but your just on a host/network that's not allowed. Maybe try `cf ssh` and try connecting from inside the CF app container? Just guessing but the service broker might be creating the user with network restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @DanielMikusa. The problem was in SSL authentication, see my answer if interested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My colleague have solved the problem at last. The problem was in that we did not provide an SSL certificate explicitly.

The URL to the SSL certificate (ca_cert_env_var in the code snippet below) to use is available inside Stratos UI under Application -> Variables -> ca_cert.

```
with urllib.request.urlopen(ca_cert_env_var) as resp:
    with open('cert.pem', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(resp.read())

db = pymysql.connect(host='abcdef.rds.amazonaws.com',
                     user='user1',
                     passwd=...,
                     db='mydb123',
                     port=1234,
                     ssl={'ca': 'cert.pem'})
```